# Reducing vertex count

Tags: edit-mode, sculpting

I'm making a low poly model of an iceberg and there is a certain part of it that has about a million vertices (which probably got there when I was sculpting the thing).[image]

Outside of Edit mode it looks just fine but I have to continue sculpting the model specifically in the place where this massive cluster is and my pc can't handle that.

It either takes 5-6 seconds after I click in sculpt mode to see any change or blender just crashes.

Is there ANY way to fix this?

Comment: Try using the Decimate modifier in object mode to reduce the geometry. It might take a while to compute but when you are happy with number of vertices apply the modifier and continue sculpting, but don't go so high on subdivision with the dynamic topology.

Comment: You can use the decimate modifier in edit mode too, only on the selected part. Just hit the space bar and type in decimate. The dyntopo also can decrease the polycount with the collapse edges function.